# gosqlite stmt is not responding and working .its stops till status buffer reader

Tags: sqlite, go

my gosqlite statement is not executing . its gets value from status and stops there . Can anyone help me.
also after running its goes upto status then its does nothing and terminal cursor is blinking.

```golang
package update

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    //      "log"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func Updatemac(db *sql.DB) {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter MAC Address to update: ")
    MAC_Address, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if MAC_Address != "\n" {
        MAC_Address = strings.TrimSuffix(MAC_Address, "\n")
    }
    ///     rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT * From wd WHERE MAC_Address = ?")
    //      fmt.Print(rows)
    //      defer rows.Close()
    //      for rows.Next() {
    //              rows.Scan(&MAC_Address)
    //      }
    fmt.Print("Status :")
    Status, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if Status != "\n" {
        Status = strings.TrimSuffix(Status, "\n")
    }
    Stmt, err := db.Prepare("UPDATE wd SET Status = ? WHERE MAC_Address = ?")
    checkErr(err)
    defer Stmt.Close()
    Stmt.Exec(Status, MAC_Address)
}

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```